# Mahout split command only choosing from one class

Tags: machine-learning, mahout

I have tried various solutions. I have tried increasing the size of dataset and also decreasing it. But when I run the mahout split command to split the dataset into training and testing sets, my testing set only consisted of data from one class.

As a result, when I run the testnb command on mahout to test the classifier, I only obtained result which tested on one class only.

How can I make Mahout split the data from all classes into the testing set?

Comment: I have three classes. How many data do I actually need to get it running

Comment: It should do it alone. What are the commands you are using? what is the version of Mahout?

Comment: I'm running mahout 0.9. I have created my dataset the same way like the 20newsgroup example. I ran the command based on mahout tutorials. mahout split -i <tfidf-vectors path> --trainingOutput train --testOutput test --randomSelectionPct 20 -ow --sequenceFiles -xm sequential

Comment: Can you check of the tf-idf/part-* file with the mahout seqdumper command? Try to find out how many vector there is

Comment: that's the thing. tfidf/part-r-00000 shows all the classes. but when being split, the testing set only consists of one class. It does not randomize the class selection.

Comment: Can you describe your data structure at least? the percentage of the classes you have? the size of the data? (how many examples you are considering to train the classifier and test it) If you don't give us enough information we can't help much.